# SQL nested IF's not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, nested-if

From the looks of it I've wrapped everything in the proper BEGIN...END statements, however the code goes through and executes almost every single line of code. I've done print statements too to make sure that both @rows variables actually do contain values greater than 0. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

```
    IF @rows > '0'

        --This agent's Tax ID number has been found to exist in AgentIdentification table
        BEGIN 

            --Set UniqueAgentId according to mapped value from AgentIdentification table
            SELECT @uniqueAgentId = UniqueAgentId
            FROM AgentIdentification
            WHERE AgentTaxId = @ssn

            --Check to make sure this record exists in UniqueAgentIdToAgentId table
            SELECT @rows = COUNT(*)
            FROM UniqueAgentIdToAgentId
            WHERE UniqueAgentId = @uniqueAgentId and AgentId = @agentId

            PRINT @rows
            IF @rows > 0                
                --Record exists in UniqueAgentIdToAgentId table
                --Check to make sure correct UniqueAgentId is mapped to correct AgentId and vice versa
                BEGIN 
                    SELECT @agentIdRows = COUNT(AgentId)
                    FROM UniqueAgentIdToAgentId
                    WHERE UniqueAgentId = @uniqueAgentId and AgentId <> @agentId

                    SELECT @uniqueIdRows = COUNT(UniqueAgentId)
                    FROM UniqueAgentIdToAgentId
                    WHERE AgentId = @agentId and UniqueAgentId <> @uniqueAgentId

                    IF @uniqueIdRows = 0 AND @agentIdRows = 0
                        BEGIN           
                            SET @returnValue = 1
                        END
                    ELSE IF @agentIdRows = 0 AND @uniqueIdRows > 0
                        BEGIN           
                            SET @returnValue = 2
                        END
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            SET @returnValue = 3
                        END
                END

            --Record does not exist in UniqueAgentIdToAgentId and will be added
            ELSE 
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO UniqueAgentIdToAgentId (UniqueAgentId, AgentId, CompanyCode, LastChangeOperator, LastChangeDate)
                    VALUES (@uniqueAgentId, @agentId, @companyCode, @lastChangeOperator, @LastChangeDate)
                    SET @returnValue = 4
                END
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

            --This agent Tax ID number does not exist on AgentIdentification table
            --Add record into Agent and AgentIdentification table
            INSERT INTO Agent (EntityType, FirstName, LastName, NameSuffix, CorporateName, LastChangeOperator, LastChangeDate)
            VALUES (@entityType, @firstName, @lastname, '', @corporateName, @lastChangeOperator, @LastChangeDate)

            SELECT @uniqueAgentId = @@IDENTITY
            SELECT UniqueAgentId
            FROM Agent

            INSERT INTO AgentIdentification (UniqueAgentId, TaxIdType, AgentTaxId, LastChangeOperator, LastChangeDate)
            VALUES (@uniqueAgentId, @taxIdType, @ssn, @lastChangeOperator, @lastChangeDate)

            --Check to make sure this record exists in UniqueAgentIdToAgentId table
            SELECT @rows = COUNT(*)
            FROM UniqueAgentIdToAgentId
            WHERE UniqueAgentId = @uniqueAgentId and AgentId = @agentId

            IF @rows > 0
                --Record exists in UniqueAgentIdToAgentId table
                --Check to make sure correct UniqueAgentId is mapped to correct AgentId and vice versa
                BEGIN 
                    SELECT @agentIdRows = COUNT(AgentId)
                    FROM UniqueAgentIdToAgentId
                    WHERE UniqueAgentId = @uniqueAgentId and AgentId <> @agentId

                    SELECT @uniqueIdRows = COUNT(UniqueAgentId)
                    FROM UniqueAgentIdToAgentId
                    WHERE AgentId = @agentId and UniqueAgentId <> @uniqueAgentId

                    IF @uniqueIdRows = 0 AND @agentIdRows = 0
                        BEGIN   
                            SET @returnValue = 5                        
                        END
                    ELSE IF @agentIdRows = 0 AND @uniqueIdRows > 0
                        BEGIN
                            SET @returnValue = 6                        
                        END
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            SET @returnValue = 7                        
                        END
                END

            --Record does not exist in UniqueAgentIdToAgentId and will be added
            ELSE 
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO UniqueAgentIdToAgentId (UniqueAgentId, AgentId, CompanyCode, LastChangeOperator, LastChangeDate)
                    VALUES (@uniqueAgentId, @agentId, @companyCode, @lastChangeOperator, @LastChangeDate)
                    SET @returnValue = 8                
                END
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: `IF @rows > '0'`, `IF @rows > 0`, `both @rows variables` Do you have two different variables named @rows, one a text type and the other a numeric, both used to track a number of rows? That's extremely confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this:

```
ELSE
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
```

Needs to be this:

```
ELSE
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
```

And this:

```
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Needs to be this:

```
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

Comment: +1 `BEGIN TRANSACTION` is a totally different thing from just `BEGIN`. `BEGIN TRANSACTION...COMMIT TRANSACTION` defines a transaction, but doesn't scope a block of statements. You need `BEGIN...END` for that.